# Rotated ImageViews overlaps each other

Tags: image, javafx, rotation, imageview, image-rotation

I want to add an rotated ImageViews to an VBox. My probelm is that the ImageViews overlaps each other and i have no idea how to solve this. Can anyone help me? That would be cool! Thanks!

My Code for the Rotation:

```
private ImageView normalizeOrientation(int orientation, ImageView iv){
        switch (orientation){
            case 2:
                iv.setRotationAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS);
                iv.setRotate(180);
                break;
            case 3:
                iv.setRotate(180);
                break;
            case 4:
                iv.setRotate(180);
                iv.setRotationAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS);
                iv.setRotate(180);
            case 5:
                iv.setRotate(90);
                iv.setRotationAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS);
                iv.setRotate(180);
                break;
            case 6:
                iv.setRotate(90);
                break;
            case 7:
                iv.setRotate(270);
                iv.setRotationAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS);
                iv.setRotate(180);
                break;
            case 8:
                iv.setRotate(270);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return iv;
    }
```

After adding rotated images to a VBox this happens:

[Overlapping Images in a VBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXL9X.jpg)

Comment: Wrap each image view in a group and add the groups to the parent, instead of the image views.

Comment: @James_D Cool, that works! Never heard something about Groups before...